# Am I adding items to my Java array wrong?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class ProjectEulerProb2 {

    int firstInt = 1, secondInt = 2, thirdInt = 0, answer = 0;
    int[] array = new int[4000000];
    int[] evenArray = new int[90];

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ProjectEulerProb2 prob = new ProjectEulerProb2();
        prob.doIt();
        prob = null;

    }

    public void doIt() {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4000000; i++) {

            if (i == 0) {
                thirdInt = firstInt + secondInt;
            }
            else {
                firstInt = secondInt;
                secondInt = thirdInt;
                thirdInt = firstInt + secondInt;
            }

            array[i] = firstInt;
            array[i + 1] = secondInt;
            array[i + 2] = thirdInt;


            if (thirdInt >= 4000000) {
                break;
            }
        }


        for (int j = 0; j <= 90; j = j + 3) {
            if (j == 0) {
                if (array[j + 1] % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("        " + array[j + 1] % 2 + "        " + array[j + 1]);
                    evenArray[j / 3] = array[j + 1];
                }
                if (array[j + 2] % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("        " + array[j + 2] % 2 + "        " + array[j + 2]);
                    evenArray[j / 3] = array[j + 2];
                }
            }

            if (array[j] % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("        " + array[j] % 2 + "      " + array[j]);
                evenArray[j / 3] = array[j];
            }

        }


        for (int u = 0; u < evenArray.length; u++) {
            if (u == 0) {
                answer = evenArray[u];
            }
            else {
                answer = answer + evenArray[u];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me find the problem? Every time I print the values of the array it comes out as 0 instead of the assigned value.

**EDIT:** Okay I took all the 'System.out.println's'
 out that I didn't need.

**EDIT 2:** Okay so I rewrote the code to not use arrays anymore. Still interested in figuring out where I went wrong with the last version though.

public class ProjectEulerProb2Other {
static int firstInt=1, secondInt=2, thirdInt=0, answer=0;

public static void main(String[] args){

```
for(int i = 0; i<=4000000;i++){
        if(i==0){
            if(firstInt%2==0){

                answer = answer+firstInt;

            }
            if(secondInt%2==0){

                answer = answer+secondInt;

            }
        thirdInt = firstInt+secondInt;
        }else{
            firstInt = secondInt;
            secondInt = thirdInt;
            thirdInt = firstInt+secondInt;
            if(thirdInt%2==0){

                answer = answer+thirdInt;

            }

        }



    if(thirdInt>=4000000){
        System.out.println(answer);

        break;

    }
}

  }

 }
```

Comment: Could you clean up the formatting, so blocks line up better, please.

Comment: You have printlns all over the place, which ones are you talking about?  Can you clean up the code just have the example you are dealing with.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need an array to solve this problem at all. Calculate the Fibonacci numbers in sequence, and each time you get an even number, add it to the result. No need to remember *all* the previous numbers, just the previous two so you can calculate the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with how you add elements to your array.

```
array[i] = firstInt;
```

Is correct. However, there are problems in your logic. Since this is probably an homework, I'll let you find them :)

**EDIT**

Okay so the problem was in this loop in your first version:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 90; j = j + 3) {
    if (j == 0) { //Bad idea!!
        if (array[j + 1] % 2 == 0) { //Always false. array[0 + 1] == 1
            System.out.println("        " + array[j + 1] % 2 + "        " + array[j + 1]);
            evenArray[j / 3] = array[j + 1];
        }
        if (array[j + 2] % 2 == 0) { //Always true. array[0 + 2] == 2
            System.out.println("        " + array[j + 2] % 2 + "        " + array[j + 2]);
            evenArray[j / 3] = array[j + 2]; 
        }
    }

    if (array[j] % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("        " + array[j] % 2 + "      " + array[j]);
        evenArray[j / 3] = array[j];
    }

}
```

My fix:

```
int jCpt = 0; //To add in evenArray in an orderly manner
for (int j = 0; jCpt < 90 && j < 4000000; ++j) { //Changed this
    if (array[j] % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("        " + array[j] % 2 + "      " + array[j]);

        evenArray[jCpt++] = array[j]; //We add alement #j from array to evenArray
        /* Equivalent of 
         * evenArray[jCpt] = array[j];
         * jCpt = jCpt + 1; 
         */
    }
}
```

But that version is probably better:

```
int evenCpt = 0; //To insert the even numbers one after the other
int fibonacciCpt = 0; //To iterate through the fibonacci numbers in array

for (; evenCpt < 90 && fibonacciCpt < 4000000; ++fibonacciCpt) {
    if (array[fibonacciCpt] % 2 == 0)
        evenArray[evenCpt++] = array[fibonacciCpt];
}
```

Congratulations, you solved Problem #2 :)

Comment: Unless teachers are assigning [Project Euler problems](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=2) as homework, it's not homework. It's generally meant to be solved independently, though.

Comment: Yeah this wasn't homework =P. I just felt like doing a Project Euler problem.

Comment: And @Shaken_Earth is only 14. Unless he skipped a few grades, he won't be assigned this kind of problem at school. Keep it up, that's amazing for your age!

Comment: I really don't see where I was illogical in my previous version though.

Comment: There you go. If anything in my changes are unclear, feel free to ask!

Comment: I don't understand what you changed and why.

Comment: You were using the same cpt for both arrays (which is a really bad practice), so I added a cpt for insersion inside the "evenArray". Also, your 'j' had no reason (I think) to be incremented by 3. So I fixed that too. The version at the bottom is the simpliest, and it works.

Comment: I incremented it by 3 because I didn't want it to keep on going over firstInt and secondInt over and over. I thought it would make the program more efficient but I'm not sure if it did. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You were skipping the first and second only once. After that, you were just skipping numbers, so that's why it was not working. As a general advice, don't try to optimize early. Make your algoritm SIMPLE and functionnal and then optimize it if needed. To skip the first and second int, you could have simply assigned them before the loop (e.g.: evenArray[0] = 2; since 1 is not even) and then initialize j=2;. But the "time saving" is not worth the added complexity.